# Error menu with the <i> glyphicon different styles

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I have a problem with working with JSP tags.

I am using a nav menu within the tag

intrudci a  to enter a glyphicon and have followed the description section.

My problem comes when I look at the browser, I caught the styles of the  I glyphicon and transforms everything. I can fix it by putting a point and not leave the  empty but this is not optimal

I attached two sacks:

The first: without putting the  using a point I used 2 different styles

[image: WITH POINT]

The second: without putting the point I mix the styles of glyphicon

[image: dotless]

CODE

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
                <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                    <li><spring:url value="/alertas" var="alertas" /><a
                        href="${alertas}">
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-2x">.</i>
                        <spring:message code="menu.dashboard" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><spring:url value="/historico" var="historico" /> <a
                    href="${historico}">
                    <span class="fa  fa-history fa-2x">.</span>
                    <spring:message code="menu.historico" /></a></li>
                    <li><spring:url value="/kpis" var="kpis" /> <a
                    href="${kpis}">
                    <span class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x">.</span>
                    <spring:message code="menu.kpis" /></a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="admin-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x">.</span>
                            <spring:message
                                    code="menu.administracion" />
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="admin-menu">
                        <li><spring:url value="/usuarios" var="usuarios" /> <a
                            href="${usuarios}">
                            <span class="fa fa-users fa-2x">.</span>
                            <spring:message
                                    code="menu.usuarios" /></a></li>
                        <li><spring:url value="/pacientes" var="pacientes" />
                            <a href="${pacientes}">
                            <span class="fa fa-street-view fa-2x">.</span>
                            <spring:message
                                    code="menu.pacientes" /></a></li>
                        <li><spring:url value="/episodios" var="episodios" />
                            <a href="${episodios}">
                            <span class="fa fa-clipboard fa-2x">.</span>
                            <spring:message
                                    code="menu.episodios" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                </sec:authorize>
            </sec:authorize>
        </ul>
```

Any solution? thank you so much!!!!

Comment: You can call me liar but I copied and pasted your code in a html page and works fine even if I delete the . maybe you have another css causing troubles.

Comment: thank you @FranciscoFernandez !! I do not understand what may be happening ... it will be a thing of the css: S

Comment: Try with a page only with font awesome reference and your code, if you have the same result is font awesome or your browser if not is some css causing troubles.